# Ansible including files which may not exist?

Tags: ansible

I am writing a playbook for creating Docker images to be used only within my office. One of my requirements is to allow other developers to easily run their own code before the docker image is built. To do this I am allowing them to add their own yml file and have it be run if a variable is set to False. I require them to have their file called {{ account }}.yml where account is another variable that must be set.

For people who don't want to run a custom play before building the image there will not be an {{ account }}.yml file. I figured that by adding the condition the error wouldn't occur because I wouldn't be trying to import the file, but even when the include should be ignored I still get an error telling me the file doesn't exist.

```
- name: Custom provisioning
  include: '{{account}}.yml'
  when: default_prebuild_provision == 'False' or generic == 'False'
```

I know my conditions work because if I change it to something like

```
- name: Custom provisioning
  shell: echo Hello World
  when: default_prebuild_provision == 'False' or generic == 'False'
```

I won't get any output because the condition fails.

Does anyone have a solution for getting around this? Also should I open a ticket for this because it seems to be a bug?

Comment: afaik this is not recommended, but if you can't find a more elegant way, you could add `ignore_errors: yes` to that specific task.

Comment: regardless of it is recommended or not, using ignore_errors: true uses the least amount of code to do exactly what a 'does the file exist, if yes then do this command' code block would do. I would happily use ignore_errors instead of creating an evaluation case wrapper myself in this scenario

Comment: This wont work. See Leitos answer. `include`s are not normal tasks. All `include`s get resolved before the playbook execution starts regardless of conditions or other statements of ignore_errors. So the file has to be there or no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

As Leito described, this is not directly possible due to the way how `include`s are handled. As a custom module this also might be pretty hard to accomplish, if even possible.

An **ugly** workaround might be, to instead give the developers the option to provide a custom playbook, then run a `shell` action, check for presence of that playbook file, and run another `ansible-playbook` process. This of course comes with many downsides where the most concerning would be that you wouldn't see the output of the 2nd playbook in the main play. But it's the only option I can imagine right now, where you can include custom tasks.

```
- name: Custom provisioning
  shell: [ -f {{account}}.yml ] && ansible-playbook ... {{account}}.yml
```

---

In case the tasks you want the developers to run, are in some way pre-defined and only differ in configuration, you could allow them to provide a custom vars file and then trigger actions in your roles depending on the defined vars. In the `include_vars` task you can ignore errors:

```
- include_vars: {{account}}.yml
  failed_when: false
```

`failed_when: false` IMHO is better than `ignore_errors: yes` because it not marks the task as failed. `ignore_errors` would still throw an error but keeps going with the play.

Alternatively, you could do something like this and fall back to a default or empty vars file:

```
- include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
   - "{{ account }}.yml"
   - "empty.yml"
```

And then run your tasks dependent on the possibly defined vars:

```
- some_other_action:
  details: some_var_from_account
  when: some_var_from_account is defined
```

Comment: I guess `failed_when: false` will mute the failures in the included file

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, please read more about in the question is posted: [Ansible include task only if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119521/ansible-include-task-only-if-file-exists)

Short answer: `when: False` won't short-circuit the include. The when clause is simply applied to all tasks inside '{{account}}.yml' when it exists or fail when it doesn't.

A solution around this: I'm not sure, but exploring the possibility of writing my own include (as a module)