# Ansible include task only if file exists

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to include a file only if it exists. This allows for custom "tasks/roles" between existing "tasks/roles" if needed by the user of my role. I found this:

```
- include: ...
  when: condition
```

But the Ansible docs state that:

> "All the tasks get evaluated, but the conditional is applied to each and every task" - http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-and-includes

So

```
- stat: path=/home/user/optional/file.yml
  register: optional_file
- include: /home/user/optional/file.yml
  when: optional_file.stat.exists
```

Will fail if the file being included doesn't exist. I guess there might be another mechanism for allowing a user to add tasks to an existing recipe. I can't let the user to add a role after mine, because they wouldn't have control of the order: their role will be executed after mine.

Comment: I spent a little bit of time working on this and it appears you are correct, it certainly fails even when the `when` condition is false.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks all for your help! I'm aswering my own question after finally trying all responses and my own question's code back in today's Ansible: **ansible 2.0.1.0**

My original code seems to work now, except the optional file I was looking was in my local machine, so I had to run stat through *local_action* and set `become: no` for that particular tasks, so ansible wouldn't attempt to do sudo in my local machine and error with: *"sudo: a password is required\n"*

```
- local_action: stat path=/home/user/optional/file.yml
  register: optional_file
  become: no
- include: /home/user/optional/file.yml
  when: optional_file.stat.exists
```

Comment: is it possible to do something similar for roles: "include" a role only if it exists? I tried with a pre_tast to check main file for role existence, save a variable and then use that variable in role inclusion, but ansible fails with `the role 'debian_stock_config' was not found`. thanks

Comment: Hi Igor, that's outside of the scope of this question, you might want to start your own, to get more attention on your specific issue.

Answer (score 37):

The `with_first_found` conditional can accomplish this without a `stat` or `local_action`. This conditional will go through a list of local files and execute the task with `item` set to the path of the first file that exists. 
Including `skip: true` on the `with_first_found` options will prevent it from failing if the file does not exist.

Example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - include: "{{ item }}"
      with_first_found:
        - files:
            - /home/user/optional/file.yml
          skip: true
```

Comment: Trying this and I am seeing this:


    ERROR! 'with_first_found' is not a valid attribute for a PlaybookInclude

Comment: I had the `include` statement as a task not at the playbook level. It works this way as a task. The included file contains only tasks though. If you need to include separate host targeted playbooks then you'll have to stat the file locally and then use that result as a conditional.

Comment: This is one well hidden feature of Ansible, but a great one, thanks ! Note that newer versions of Ansible have switched to using `lookup` with the `first_found` filter. see  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/first_found.html

Answer (score 9):

In Ansible 2.5 and above, it can be done using tests like this:

```yaml
- include: /home/user/optional/file.yml
  when: "'/home/user/optional/file.yml' is file"
```

More details: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-paths

Comment: In my setup (Ansible 2.10), a full path is required, so to get this to work inside a role I had to use `when: (role_path, '/templates/', item, '.yml.j2') | join('') is file`

Comment: This looks nice in principle, **but** note that tests are always evaluated on the local host (the one running Ansible) and not the target host. That is fine for this question's use case, but might not be for others.

Answer (score 6):

I using something similar but for the file module and what did the trick for me is to check for the variable definition, try something like:

```
when: optional_file.stat.exists is defined and optional_file.stat.exists
```

the task will run only when the variable exists.

Comment: Thanks, it appears that when will work without the `optional_file.stat.exists is defined`. I'm still trying to determine what change allowed that.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not wrong, you want to continue the playbook even the when statement false?

If so, please add this line after `when:`

```
ignore_errors: True
```

So your tasks will be look like this:

```
- stat: path=/home/user/optional/file.yml
  register: optional_file
- include: /home/user/optional/file.yml
  when: optional_file.stat.exists
  ignore_errors: True
```

Please let me know, if I understand your question correctly, or can help further. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it seems you understand the question, but this won't work. ignore_errors won't ignore the fact that the file is missing. I think http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands vaguely talks about this when it says: "Note that the above system only governs the failure of the particular task, so if you have an undefined variable used, it will still raise an error that users will need to address." This error is one of those that will stop the user.

Answer (score 2):

I could spend time here to bash ansible's error handling provisions, but in short, you are right and you can't use `stat` module for this purpose due to stated reasons.

Simplest solution for most ansible problems is to do it outside ansible. E.g.

```
- shell: test -f /home/user/optional/file.yml     # or use -r if you're too particular.
  register: optional_file
  failed_when: False
- include: /home/user/optional/file.yml
  when: optional_file.rc == 0
- debug: msg="/home/user/optional/file.yml did not exist and was not included"
  when: optional_file.rc != 0
```

*** `failed_when`** added to avoid host getting excluded from further tasks when the file doesn't exist.

Comment: This is an amazing way to do it. Thanks. I used test -d to check for directories and later realised the value of the failed_when flag. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Using ansible-2.1.0, I'm able to use snippets like this in my playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Determine if local playbook exists
      local_action: stat path=local.yml
      register: st

- include: local.yml
  when: st.stat.exists
```

I get no errors/failures when `local.yml` does not exist, and the playbook is executed (as a playbook, meaning it starts with the `hosts:` line, etc.)

You can do the same at the task level instead with similar code.
Using `stat` appears to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the option to use a Jinja2 filter for that:

```
 - set_fact: optional_file="/home/user/optional/file.yml"

 - include: ....
   when: optional_file|exists
```

Comment: On Ansible 2.9.1, I get `no filter named 'exists'`

Comment: Have you tried using `is exists` instead of `| exists` ?

Comment: Just now I tried your suggestion and was unable to make it work. Do you mean using `local_action: stat ...` as shown in the accepted answer?

Comment: Then this filter might have been removed in recent versions of Ansible, haven't checked yet. Fee free to ignore my answer and use the accepted one indeed!

Answer (score 1):

The best option I have come up with so far is this:

```
- include: "{{ hook_variable | default(lookup('pipe', 'pwd') ~ '/hooks/empty.yml') }}"
```

It's not exactly an "if-exists", but it gives users of your role the same result. Create a few variables within your role and a default empty file. The Jinja filters "default" and "lookup" take care of falling back on the empty file in case the variable was not set.

For convenience, a user could use the `{{ playbook_dir }}` variable for setting the paths:

```
hook_variable: "{{ playbook_dir }}/hooks/tasks-file.yml"
```

Comment: This ONLY works for Ansible v1.9 and below. Ansible v2.0 and up should use the `when: include_file_variable is defined` suggested by @olluch

Comment: Thanks! I used `{{ playbook_dir }}` in my real code, I just left it out of the example for simplicity sake.