# ansible - check if file exists on *local* machine

Tags: ansible

I have a situation where I need to check the status of a file on the local machine (the one where I will call `ansible-playbook ...`).

If a file that is created by the user exists, it needs to be copied over to the remote host(s). If it doesn't exist, then none of the remote hosts need it.

I know I've done things like :

```
- name: Check for ~/.blah/config
  stat: path=/home/ubuntu/.blah/config
  register: stat_blah_config

- name: Do something with blah config
  shell: ~/do_something_with_config.sh
  when: stat_aws_config.stat.exists == true
```

But that will only work if the file exists remotely. Is there a way to conditionally execute a task (like copy) only if the file exists *locally* (have the `stat` in the first task execute locally instead of remotely), and fail silently if it does not? I'm not sure if ansible has this kind of functionality, but it would be useful.

Comment: Actually, I may have already found an answer here, using `local_action`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855236/copy-local-file-if-exists-using-ansible?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible include task only if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119521/ansible-include-task-only-if-file-exists)

Answer (score 46):

Delegating the tasks to the localhost via the [delegate_to](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) statement should do what you want:

```yaml
- name: Check for ~/.blah/config
  delegate_to: localhost
  stat:
    path: /home/ubuntu/.blah/config
  register: stat_blah_config
```

Comment: Are there any special permission settings that need to be set in order to use `local_action`? I keep getting "permission denied" errors:
`TASK: [blah_stuff | Check for ~/.blah/config] ************************************** 
failed: [i-34b724e0 -> 127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
BECOME-SUCCESS-tqbkvkywytucgnfrjbmokwelpwddzevz
/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1444157688.04-230781782204943/stat: Permission denied`

I did try using `sudo: true` but that didn't seem to help

Comment: If `sudo:true` is failing then make sure the user you are running ansible as has the ability to sudo without a password.  Ansible won't prompt you for a password, so if it can't perform the task then it will fail.

Comment: you can try to add: `become: false` in that case.

Answer (score 7):

This also works, and saves executing a task:

```yaml
when: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.fileglob', '/home/ubuntu/.blah/config') != [] }}"
```

`fileglob` always looks on the local machine.

Comment: `[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}.`